# How to take input from textbox to array?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i am using this code snippet to pass the actual value to array. but i want to take the value passed from textbox to array how to do this?

html code:

```
<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
<input type="text" name="cost" value=" ">
```

javascript code:

```
multipliers = [5, 6, 5];
```

instead of 5,6,5 i should get values from textfield how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9uRj/)

An input array would be appropriate:

```
<form name="myForm">
<input type="text" name="cost[]" value="1">
<input type="text" name="cost[]" value="2">
<input type="text" name="cost[]" value="3">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var list = document.myForm.elements['cost[]'];
var multipliers = [];

for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++)
{
    multipliers.push(list[i].value);    
}

console.log(multipliers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll` since you don't seem to be having ids for your elements.

```
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[name=cost]'), // get all elements with name = cost
    values = [], 
    i = 0;
for(i=0; i<nodes.length; i++) 
    values.push(parseInt(nodes[i].value, 10));
console.log(values);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VGahh/1/)**

Comment: You can use `getElementsByName` for clearer code with more browser compatibility.

Comment: @Quentin it's better than `querySelectorAll` but `getElementsByName` is buggy in IE < 10.

Answer (score -2):

```
<form name="myForm">
      <input type="text" name="cost[]" value="1">
      <input type="text" name="cost[]" value="2">
      <input type="text" name="cost[]" value="3">
   </form>


  var allElements= document.myForm.elements['cost[]'];
    var arr= [];

      for(var i=0; i<allElements.length; i++)
        arr.push(allElements[i].value);
```

Comment: Giving an ID to each one is a horribly inefficient way of doing this, and the question is asking about creating an array of the values, not the DOM nodes. (And `[]` is preferred over `new Array()`)

Comment: How is this programming? Giving them all individual IDs and having to repeat the code everytime another is added? What if there are 150 cost inputs?

Comment: @MrCode Thanks i updated my answer.But i thought only 3 are there